# Having shirk thoughts. Please help?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, allah, sin, belief

Asalamualaikum,

Firstly, I would like to say I am a Muslimah.

A few months ago, I wasn’t very practicing. I was very eager to know what my future life is like. So I decided to contact a Hindu astrologer (prem jyotish). He explained that he somehow looks at planets to forecast my future. I don’t believe that people can tell future by looking at planets.

Anyways, during Ramadan I was researching to know more about Islam. Then I found out that astrology is actually a MINOR SHIRK. I was so sad I started crying. I knew it was sin but didn’t know it was that big deal. I repented and recited the shahadah.

Now here is the real problem. Every time I think about my future, I always have shaitaan whispering “remember that the astrologer said you will have lots of wealth by February”. And I am believing it   . You know why? Because many people on google reviews are saying his predictions are always accurate. I don’t wanna believe it as it is shirk. But how can I not believe in it when so many people are saying his predictions are always right?

I know he cannot tell my future by looking at stars and planets. An Islamic source said he contacts jinns to forecast my future. Apparently jinns do have limited knowledge about our future but not all.

Please help. Am I committing shirk?

Comment: Jazakallah to both! I know that intention is very important in Islam. And committing shirk is definitely not my intention. So do I still get sin?

Comment: @Muslimah222 As Salaamu 3laykum, I hope you are doing well. As long as your intention is good and you do not hurt anyone (physically, mentally, emotionally, etc.) then it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

> "Say, ˹O Prophet,˺ “None in the heavens and the earth has knowledge of the unseen except Allah. Nor do they know when they will be resurrected." Quran 27:65

No one knows the unseen except Allah. The jinns aren't smart enough:

> "Indeed, the scheme of Satan is ever weak." Quran 4:76.

You also need to think about logic, how can a human or a jinn know the future if it still hasn't happened and if they aren't smart enough?

So do NOT believe in what he says. You believe in the day of judgement, she doesn't. When we believe in something, we start seeing stuff in our daily lives that's in agreement with our beliefs.

You also have to think that only the people who have got what they predicted left a review. So there may be a lot of people who didn't have the predictions right but you don't see it.

And after all, who tells you that it's not Allah that gave those people money in February (for example) to test them, see if they believe in their predictions or not? After all, it's Allah that gives the money, it's not the money that comes.

Shirk is not worth it. If Allah wants you to have something, you *will* have that thing, if he doesn't you will not have that thing. May Allah guide and forgive us all. Ameen

Answer (score -1):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. First I would like to say I am happy that you have that feeling of being in the wrong and trying to learn more about Islam. That is very good and never give that up no matter what negative thoughts come to you.

When it comes to what you had asked regarding the astrologer, well that is forbidden. As seen from these ahadith:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said to me: “O ‘Ali, do wudoo’ properly even if it is difficult for you; do not consume charity; do not mate a donkey with a horse; **and do not sit with astrologers.**” (Musnad Ahmad , Grade: Hasan because of corroborating evidence; this is a weak isnad because of the weakness of Haroon bin Muslim)

> Zayd ibn Khalid reported: The Messenger of ALLAH, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “ALLAH said: Among my servants are those who awaken with faith in me and disbelief in me. Whoever said we have been given rain due to the favor and mercy of Allah, he is a believer in me and a disbeliever in the stars. **Whoever said we have been given rain due to the rising of this star, he has disbelieved in Me and has put his faith in the stars.**” (Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 810, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 71)

> “If one goes to a soothsayer, asks about something, and believes it, his prayer will not be accepted for forty days.” [Muslim]

> “Divination and taking omens from the flight of birds are types of idolatry.” [Abu Dawud]

> “If one takes knowledge from the stars [i.e., astrology], he in fact takes a branch of sorcery. The more knowledge he gains [of that], the more sin he gains.” [Abu Dawud; commentary from Munawi, Fayd al-Qadir]

However, when it comes to divination there is an interesting hadith that I have never seen quoted!

> I said: Messenger of ALLAH! among us there are men who practice divination by drawing lines. He said: There was a Prophet who drew lines, so if anyone does it as he drew lines, that is right. (Abu Dawud , Grade: Sahih (Al-Albani))

I will say with the hadith just mentioned it is only for those that followed that specific knowledge from a previous Prophet (peace be upon him) otherwise we cannot use this as proof to use any divination method. So we cannot say all divination is evil. But who do we know in today's world that knows the rare science of drawing lines to get answers.

Coming back to the main point is that the main reliance has always been put on ALLAH (Glory Be To Him). Because you have to remember that Islam is all about not committing shirk/evil and staying far away from it. ​It is the same with dajjal at the end of times. Even if he shows you all the miracles and cool things, do not go to him. Or with like drinking alcohol it might give benefits to some people by relaxing them ,etc. however it has been outright prohibited. Or with eating pork it might be somewhat beneficial but has been prohibited. So what has been prohibited we do not do no matter how many reviews or if his predictions come true.

**Conclusion**

If you have some belief in him then I would renew your shahadah. Furthermore, belief in Islam is 100 percent , not 99.99% or less. So if you have some belief in that astrologer then you should repent and redo your shahadah. Now thoughts might bombard you however, shift your focus to reading the Quraan and doing dhikr. Perhaps start meditating or go outside and volunteer. There are many things a person can do. When it comes to the person you visited, he might have a strong power of intuition or something else is going on behind the scenes. ALLAH (Glory Be To Him) knows best. **However, when there is clear evidence to stay away from astrologers then we have to follow that regardless of any level of benefit it might bring you.** I would suggest focusing on becoming more pure hearted and having better moral character. Learning more about Islam is something you can do in conjunction. There is much to do in this life and I hope you will do well.

**Have a nice day!**